# Inner angles in polygons

Tags: geometry, polygons

A point of a polygon is called convex if it's inner angle is less than 180 degrees. Prove that in every simple polygon there is at least one convex point.

Comment: You probably mean *vertex* instead of *point*.

Comment: Yes we can also say vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the inner angles of a simple polygon with $n$ sides is $(n-2)\pi$.

If all inner angles were greater than or equal to $\pi$, then that sum would be at least $n\pi$, which it isn't. Hence, at least one inner angle is less than $\pi$.

This argument actually implies that there are at least *two* convex vertices.

Comment: For a nice proof of the sum of inner angles, see [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9489.html) by Devadoss and O'Rourke. Chapter 1, which contains the proof and much more, is freely available.